# How to communicate between two java servers using public private key API token

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have two Java Spring applications, one is working as client and other as server. Client is Spring RESTful service.

My requirement is:

Once a server wants to communicate with a client, it should send some token. The token will get validated by client. If the token is valid then client performs some task and sends success result. Otherwise the response will be like not valid token and client does not perform any task for that request.

Comment: More specifically i am interested in API.   thanks in advance..

Comment: so, basically what you call the "client" is actually the server and the opposite. I suggest you to clarify better your question. I'm afraid you have some confusion in  mind about the client/server interaction.

Comment: I have two Spring rest application, where one will work as Server and other as Client.   1> Server application should make a Rest call to Client Application (Client is also rest application) with some token. 2> Client will accept the token, validate it and if token is valid client perform some task and return success response(200) else token is not valid should response (203) invalid token. My concern is how to manage the token. so need help in Key-API tool.

Comment: I don't want to be pedantic, but there's no such thing as a server contacting the client in a request/response protocol. The initiating entity *is* the client, period. And this is not secondary since we are discussing about REST. However, probably you'll want to add a little step where the client requests the token to the server. So, the client will contact the server presenting some credentials and the server provides it a valid token. It goes this way because the server has some resources the client **is willing to access**. Who's validating is *not* client. It's the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is JWT token, you can learn JWT token and java in [JWT token](https://jwt.io/), using the [java lib](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) to generate token and validate.

The way to transfer token is to add custom header in request header, so you can just add a filter to intercept  the request and validate the token.

If you want use authority not just a simple token you can use spring security and JWT token, the demo and reference can see [REST Security with JWT using Java and Spring Security](https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java) and [demo](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo).

In my project,I using spring security+ spring session rest+ hazelcast,it's also a way to protect my rest api by token.

You can chose the method you need and if any question you can comment under the answer.